# How to store the real schema of the document as meta in talend tXMLMap component?

Tags: talend

I'm using a talend tXMLMap component to mapping a xml to other structure and want to store the schema of input xml as meta so that it can be reused by other colleagues.

The screenshot is as follow:

[The schema in the tXMLMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXEk0.jpg)

Sorry for the image can't be shown as embedded because of my low reputation score.

The output schema is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema>
    <column comment="" default="" key="false" label="CreditMemoPayload"
        length="-1" nullable="true"
        originalDbColumnName="CreditMemoPayload" originalLength="-1"
        pattern="null" precision="-1" talendType="id_Document" type="id_String"/>
</schema>
```

My problem is there is only one column with document type, when exporting the schema, I can only export the column name, but not the real structure of the document. I don't know how to achieve this goal, and any suggestion would be very appreciative, thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to export the actual XML tree definition. You probably need to go the other way  around: define your XML structure als managed Metadata, then use it in your tXMLMap by right clicking the Document type column as seen here for example: https://help.talend.com/reader/ixBASPZJ7IvqUQVupZwWbg/EFuE5Nul595D24TRwbFnbw (you also can import directly from file like an XSD there, if you like)

Comment: @deR_Ed Thanks for your help, the answer has help me resolved the problem, how could I mark your answer as the right answer?

Comment: you don't because I couldn't answer your initial question. But if my comment helped you, then an upvote would be nice :)

Comment: @deR_Ed So how could I upvote?